# Div height 100% makes page to have scroll

Tags: html, sticky-footer

I have following structure:

```
<header></header>
<nav></nav>
<section id="mainContainer">
<section id="innerContainer">
</section>
</section>
<footer></footer>
```

And following css:

```
html {
    height: 100% !important;
}

body {
    height: 100% !important;
}

body header {
    min-width: 1280px;
    height: 78px;
}

body nav {
    height: 41px;
}

body section#mainContainer {
    height: 100%;
}

body section div#innerContainer {
    height: 100%;
}

body footer {
    height: 48px;
}
```

The main goal is - to make sticky footer. But css config like this only makes scroll appear on my page. I`ve already tryed all possible variations of making sticky footers, but all of them gave me the same result. What I`m doing wrong.

Comment: you are missing margin: 0px; and box-sizing: border-box; in some places. Read some documentation about these properties.

Comment: You have `height:100%` and then one with `height:48px`, `height:41px` and `height:78px`. This will make it `100% + 48px + 78px + 42px` and therefore the scroll. It is more than 100%.

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen don't forget 78px+41px too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting scroll because of these

```
body section#mainContainer {
    height: 100%;
}

body section div#innerContainer {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And you are adding a header, nav and footer which causes page to increase height i.e 100% + 78px + 41px+ 48px;

If you need a sticky footer than go for [ryan fait's sticky footer](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/&ei=9wCIUP-cAYLNrQf-14DoAw&usg=AFQjCNH2eGGZjDDeJcH7bSZswM4d0AnDTw)

Answer (score 0):

use fixed for your footer

```
body footer {
  position: fixed;     
  right: 0;
  left: 0;  
  bottom: 0;    
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't be fixed that way.